# how to make permission for PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS without intervention from the user

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-apps-script

i want to make a permission for android manifest this permission is

> android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS

for make the android system track my app statistics
but the problem is that the system doesn't respond to the code in the manifest .

the code is :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

my question is that how to make that without intervention from the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it's possible, or advisable if it is possible, to activate a permission without intervention from the user.
That's why it's called a "permission", because you need to request the user's permission in order to access that functionality in Android.
For more information regarding permissions, see:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes

Anything that requires "permission" requires the user's express consent, because it uses restricted data.